# Splitting Line at Whitespace in Older Octave Versions

Tags: string, parsing, file-io, octave

I'm parsing an ASCII text file using line-oriented input with:

```
    fid = fopen("myFileName", "r");    % open data file
    fgetl(fid);                        % get header variables
```

For the next line of the file I want to parse it and split the line where there is one or more whitespaces (i.e., '\s+').  Newer versions of Octave have a `'split'` option for the `regexp` built-in command.  However, the version of Octave that I'm using is 3.4.3, and I don't have the ability to upgrade to anything newer at the moment.  The `'split'` option is not recognized, so I'm looking for a workaround.  The `strsplit` command doesn't seem to allow using `fgetl(fid)` for the string argument as in:

```
    myVar = strsplit(fgetl(fid), "\s*", "delilmetertype", "regularexpression")
```

Is there something else that might work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The `regexp` function does support the `'match'` output type, even going back to Octave version 3.4. So instead of using a pattern of whitespace (`\s+`) as a delimiter, use `regexp` to return a list of matches for any number of non-whitespace characters (`\S+`).

For example

```
str = 'This is a string with       some space    characters';
m = regexp(str, '(\S+)', 'match')
```

The `'match'` option is the same as the fourth positional return value, so the following equivalent call works as well

```
[~, ~, ~, m] = regexp(str, '(\S+)')
```